# Ubuntu Studio recommended install method on new Dell laptop with hybrid drive

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ubuntu-studio

I have a new Dell laptop with a hybrid drive, that I would like to install Ubuntu Studio 19.10 on. What is the recommended method? I have never owned a computer with a hybrid drive before. Should Ubuntu Studio be installed using the drive as a RAID? Alternatively, installing Ubuntu Studio on the SSD part of the drive will speed up the boot and performance times, but it is only 256 GB. I use Bitwig Studio 3.1.2 and it isn't possible to move (unfortunately) all of the Bitwig folder contents in the /home/user/Bitwig\ Studio/ directory to another location. Thirdly, I assume that the non-SSD part of the drive would have to have a separate mount point such as /data which would require administrator privileges???

Answer (score 0):

The hybrid drive should appear no differently than any other HDD, the SSD is just used internally as a cache to improve HDD performance. The HDD does not have a separate mount point. Therefore, follow the normal process:

Download Ubuntu Studio from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions:
On a [Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)
or on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: Sooo, only the EFI partition should be on the SSD? I installed Ubuntu Studio using the advanced partitioning tool during the install, and formatted a swap and root partition on the SSD. I then formatted a /home partition on the HDD that included the full size of the drive. I am worried as to whether what I have done creates an unstable system...

I have seen other recommendations that the entire system should be installed on the SSD and then format the HDD and set the mount point as /data, but that means that the /etc/fstab has to be edited so that /data gets mounted for the user...